What is prohibited in Idolatry: Form or Symbol?
Do the prohibitions related to idolatry, that concern bnei noach, apply to symbol or form?
What I mean by symbol or form:

Symbol: status of a concept that is worshipped
Form: physical being actively worshipped (past/present)

For example: If I were to make a statue of Yeshu, not for religious purposes (disregard the prohibition of making forbidden images, and of chasdad), does that sculpture get classified as an idol because Yeshu is a known worshipped religious symbol? Or not because I did not create it with the intention of worship and the physical form of >that< statue has not been worshipped.
There are some sources that I found that seem to corroborate the prohibition of form over symbol view. This response by rabbi Immanuel Schochet from the AskNoach website forum:

Shalom Rabbi-
In my house, we have quite a large and expensive collection of American Indian pottery. I noticed that some of the pottery pieces have designs and paintings on them that, I would assume, are ancient Native American gods. Some of them look like kachina dolls, and some of the designs look like the sun with a face on it, etc. Is it OK for me to have these things in the house for decoration? I don't know if the Native Americans worship these things anymore.
Rabbi Immanuel Schochet:
Since they are sold from the outset as decorations, and the figures are merely painted on the pottery, as opposed to three-dimensional figures, there should not be a problem even with regard to "images."

There is also the famous story of Rabban Gamaliel and the aphrodite bathhouse. Although Aphrodite was worshipped in that period, it was a religious symbol. That specific statue wasn't created for idol worship.
Regarding this problem, I have some theoretical situations that would be relevant, like:
Imagine a person working at an animation studio, and they are tasked with drawing and animating a show with characters from mythology, or that has a picture of Yeshu or even him as a character. Would drawing/ animating them constitute making an idol if the show is obviously fantasy/ fiction, and not a religious representation?
What if you are tasked with building that bathhouse, and you have to make the statue; or, you have to do a bathhouse that has a yeshu statue for example, if one day the bathhouse is closed and the yeshu statue gets sold/ gifted to a church and then it gets used in worship?
If one person worships a digital 2d image on a computer, or printed photo, do all copies of that image/ photo become idols? If by form, only that photo/ computer screen would be considered idols, if not, all copies would be.
All this I suppose could be different for Jews and non-Jews, the focus of the question is regarding Bnei noach, but feel free to give a more complete answer if you'd like.

In general, Jewish Halachah doesn't go into details of Noahide observance. Regarding specific conduct, I would advise asking a rabbi.
